# Composition animation on a visual sub channel

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal

I use the new [Composition Animation API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/graphics/composition-animation) in UWP (Windows 10 1607) to animate a custom control. I want changes of the vertical offset of its children to be animated, but not changes to the horizontal offset.

I can animate the whole offset (X and Y) like this:

```
var offsetAnimation = compositor.CreateVector3KeyFrameAnimation();
offsetAnimation.Target = "Offset";
offsetAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);            
offsetAnimation.InsertExpressionKeyFrame(1.0f, "This.FinalValue");
animationCollection["Offset"] = offsetAnimation;
var visual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(child);
visual.ImplicitAnimations = animationCollection;
```

I expected this code to only animate the Y offset of the child, but it doesn't display any animation at all:

```
 var offsetAnimation = compositor.CreateScalarKeyFrameAnimation();
 offsetAnimation.Target = "Offset.Y";
 offsetAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);
 offsetAnimation.InsertExpressionKeyFrame(1.0f, "This.FinalValue");
 animationCollection["Offset"] = offsetAnimation;
 var visual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(child);
 visual.ImplicitAnimations = animationCollection;
```

Setting Target to "Offset.y" or the trigger to "Offset.Y" doesn't help.

I haven't found an example using visual sub channels in the documentation, so I would appreciate any help on how to only animate the y channel of the offset.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code snippet, you set a `Offset` trigger for the animation. That means once the offset of `child` is changed, this animation will started. And you set 'This.FinalValue' for the `ExpressionKeyFrame`, so it will bind the value you set to the new offset and it will animate to that new value.

So we if we just set the new offset to only have `y` value changed (let `x` and `z` be same as the old one), the animation will only animate the `y` channel.

Code like follows:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtanimation" Text="animation test" Height="30" Width="100" Foreground="Red" ></TextBlock>
<Button x:Name="btnanimate" Click="btnanimate_Click" Content="Animate y" Margin="60"></Button>
```

Code behind:

```
Visual visual;  
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    visual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(txtanimation);
    Compositor compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(txtanimation).Compositor;
    ImplicitAnimationCollection animationCollection = compositor.CreateImplicitAnimationCollection();
    Vector3KeyFrameAnimation offsetAnimation = compositor.CreateVector3KeyFrameAnimation();
    offsetAnimation.Target = "Offset";
    offsetAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.5);
    offsetAnimation.InsertExpressionKeyFrame(1.0f, "This.FinalValue");    
    animationCollection["Offset"] = offsetAnimation;
    visual.ImplicitAnimations = animationCollection; 
}

private void btnanimate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{        
     visual.Offset=visual.Offset+ new System.Numerics.Vector3(0f, 400f, 0f);
}
```

And the result:
[image]

More samples please reference [WindowsUIDevLabs](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs). And more details you can reference videos like [Implicit Animations](https://channel9.msdn.com/events/build/2016/p484).